# Classy way to hide unused low voltage cut outs or should I just drywall over and paint?

Tags: drywall, low-voltage

In a home I recently purchased, there are a lot of cut outs for low voltage in places I do not plan to use. The wiring is there in some cases, but I don't plan to use many of these locations. They are currently covered with blank wall plates.

When I had some electrical work, the Electrician said for the low voltage I could just take photos, mark where they are and then sheet rock / spackle / paint over them and there wouldn't be a problem since they are not active. He said I *could* do the same with the electrical in weir places, but recommended I do not because it could make electrical system troubleshooting harder in the future if you don't know its there.

I wanted to know if there was a technique to cover these in a a nicer way, but still keep them more accessible. E.g., I cut out a piece of drywall and paint it, and then use some type of material around the frame and it will look nice? I can just pop it out later if needed?

Or, should I just take good notes and pictures and cover these up since I don't plan to use them in the next 5 - 10 years. Shouldn't be an issue to cut our drywall some point in the future, right?

Examples:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you cover them with drywall and attach a magnet to the back so you can very easily find them later? Say you lose the pictures/notes of where they are? The magnet would be so easy to find.

Comment: Only if you knew it was there. Notes get lost, things get forgotten, houses get sold. A blank plate is unequivocal.

Comment: @Jax i like this idea in addition to drywalling over. I will probably end up taking photos and notes, make multiple copies, and laminate them. I don't think I'd ever need them, but you never know what i or next owners may want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are live connected wires in any of those junction boxes then you cannot just drywall over them. They have to be accessible, so stick with the cover plates. The low voltage ones could be patched over and the walls painted. Just take some good measurements for the future. In 5 or 10 years everything will probably be wireless and we won't need any wire for anything...

Comment: Active line voltage needs a cover plate. Decommissioned line voltage is supposed to be removed, so any line voltage boxes should be considered active, even if the circuit is off/disconnected. Low voltage you can do whatever, but blank plates will be good karma for the next person who wants wires, even if it's you in a few years. **Paint the cover plates to match the walls and they will be much less noticeable.** As a wireless technician, I can assure you that good wireless is built on wires & fibers. Penetration of wall materials is awful for quality connections.

Comment: Are the old low voltage wires part of a decommissioned system? Has any low voltage transformer been removed or disconnected. If the wires are fully dead and/or isolated, you can remove the junction box, fold the wires back, and then patch the drywall hole.

Comment: @JohnCanon they are just wires - the all come to one place luckily, just mostly cat5 and coax for the low voltage stuff. They were just there; the builder clearly had a different vision for how to layout the house.